# Automatically wrap NSTextField using Auto Layout

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, appkit

How does one go about having auto-layout automatically wrap an NSTextField to multiple lines as the width of the NSTextField changes?

I have numerous NSTextFields displaying static text (i.e.: labels) in an inspector pane. As the inspector pane is resized by the user, I would like the right hand side labels to reflow to multiple lines if need be.

(The Finder's Get Info panel does this.)

But I haven't been able to figure out the proper combination of auto layout constraints to allow this behavior. In all case, the NSTextFields on the right refuse to wrap. (Unless I explicitly add a height constraint that would allow it to.)

The view hierarchy is such that each gray band is a view containing two NSTextFields, the property name on the left and the property value on the right. As the user resizes the inspector pane, I would like the property value label to auto-resize it's height as need-be.

Current situation:

[image: Text fields not wrapping.]

What I would like to have happen:

[image]

(Note that this behavior is different than most Stack Overflow questions I came across regarding NSTextFields and auto layout. Those questions wanted the text field to grow while the user is typing. In this situation, the text is static and the NSTextField is configured to look like a label.)

**Update 1.0**

Taking @hamstergene's suggestion, I subclassed NSTextField and made a little sample application. For the most part, it now works, but there's now a small layout issue that I suspect is a result of the NSTextField's frame not being entirely in sync with what auto-layout expects it to be. In the screenshot below, the right-hand side labels are all vertically spaced with a `top` constraint. As the window is resized, the `Where` field is getting properly resized and wrapped. However, the `Kind` text field does not get pushed down until I resize the window "one more pixel".

[image]
Example: If I resize the window to just the right width that the `Where` textfield does it's first wrap, then I get the results in the middle image. If I resize the window one more pixel, then the `Kind` field's vertical location is properly set.

I suspect that's because auto-layout is doing it's pass and then the frames are getting explicitly set. I imagine auto-layout doesn't see that on that pass but does it it on the next pass, and updates the positions accordingly.

Assuming that's the issue, how do I inform auto-layout of these changes I'm doing in `setFrameSize` so that it can run the layout again. (And, most importantly, not get caught in recursive state of layout-setFrameSize-layout-etc...)

**Solution**

I've come up with a solution that appears to work exactly how I was hoping. Instead of subclassing `NSTextField`, I just override `layout` in the `superview` of the `NSTextField` in question. Within `layout`, I set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` on the text field and then trigger a layout pass. That appears to be enough to get it mostly working, but it leaves the annoying issue of the layout being briefly "wrong". (See note above).

The solution to that appears to be to call `setNeedsDisplay` and then everything Just Works.

```
    - (void)layout {
      NSTextField *textField = ...;
      NSRect oldTextFieldFrame = textField.frame;

      [textField setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:NSWidth(self.bounds) - NSMinX(textField.frame) - 12.0];

      [super layout];

      NSRect newTextFieldFrame = textField.frame;
      if (oldTextFieldFrame.size.height != newTextFieldFrame.size.height) {
        [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If inspector pane width will never change, just check "First Runtime Layout Width" in IB (note it's 10.8+ feature).

But allowing inspector to have variable width at the same time is not possible to achieve with constraints alone. There is a weak point somewhere in AutoLayout regarding this.

I was able to achieve reliable behaviour by subclassing the text field like this:

```
- (NSSize) intrinsicContentSize;
{
    const CGFloat magic = -4;

    NSSize rv;
    if ([[self cell] wraps] && self.frame.size.height > 1)
        rv = [[self cell] cellSizeForBounds:NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width + magic, 20000)];
    else
        rv = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    return rv;
}

- (void) layout;
{
    [super layout];
    [self invalidateWordWrappedContentSizeIfNeeded];
}

- (void) setFrameSize:(NSSize)newSize;
{
    [super setFrameSize:newSize];
    [self invalidateWordWrappedContentSizeIfNeeded];
}

- (void) invalidateWordWrappedContentSizeIfNeeded;
{
    NSSize a = m_previousIntrinsicContentSize;
    NSSize b = self.intrinsicContentSize;
    if (!NSEqualSizes(a, b))
    {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
    m_previousIntrinsicContentSize = b;
}
```

In either case, the constraints must be set the obvious way (you have probably already tried it): high vertical hugging priority, low horizontal, pin all four edges to superview and/or sibling views.

Comment: The width of the inspector is variable and is user controlled. It is not controlled (nor defined by) any constraints. Only the gray views and the NSTextField labels in the screenshots are using auto layout. (And all of this is done in code, not in Interface Builder.) I'll re-visit subclassing and manually doing layout in `layout` but I was hoping to minic the wrapping behavior seen in Finder's Get Info panel using only constraints.

Comment: In the end, setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth was the key to getting a solution in place

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to get this working, assuming you're using an `NSViewController`-based solution is this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayout {
    [super viewDidLayout];
    self.aTextField.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.aTextField.frame.size.width;
    [self.view layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
}
```

This simply lets the constraint system solve for the width (height will be unsolvable on this run so will be what ever you initially set it to), then you apply that width as the max layout width and do another constraint based layout pass.

No subclassing, no mucking with a view's layout methods, no notifications. If you aren't using `NSViewController` you can tweak this solution so that it works in most cases (subclassing textfield, in a custom view, etc.).

Most of this came from the swell http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html (look at the *Intrinsic Content Size of Multi-Line Text* section).

Answer (score 1):

Set in the size inspector tab in section Text Field Preferred Width to "First Runtime layout Width"

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and is a bit more elegant. Additionally i've made a little sample project on [Github](https://github.com/timtwotoes/Todo)

```
public class DynamicTextField: NSTextField {
   public override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
      if cell!.wraps {
         let fictionalBounds = NSRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY, width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
         return cell!.cellSize(forBounds: fictionalBounds)
      } else {
         return super.intrinsicContentSize
      }
   }

   public override func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
      super.textDidChange(notification)

      if cell!.wraps {
         validatingEditing()
         invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
      }
   }
}
```